# How to get Back button(on device) like functionality on app bar back arrow on top right corner

Tags: java, android

I have a button which takes me back to the home screen. But this loads the screen everytime i click on that button. But when I press the back button(given by android on phone) then it doesn't load the page again and again. I don't want that my activity is loaded again and I want to get the same functionality as the back button.
I have tried

```
Intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
```

But this loads the whole activity again and again.
Any suggestions are valuable. The main screen has a map which gets loaded evertime I hit that button.

Comment: if you want to stop activity from reopening from the background you can just use finish() after moving to the next activity   //startActivity(intent);finish();

Comment: Exactly I don't want to stop it from reopening. But I want to get the same behavior which the back button gives (that is doesn't load everything again) in the button that I have in the second activity. If i finish the activity then it will load everything again which is slower.@Shivam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand two concepts here -

1. Task and Back Stack
2. LaunchMode

**Task and Back Stack**:

A task is a collection of activities that users interact with when performing a certain job. The activities are arranged in a stack—the back stack)—in the order in which each activity is opened.  In simple word back stack is just an stack of activity which grown as user start launching new activities in FILO (First in Last Out) manner.

> If the user presses the **Back(on device)** button, that new activity
> is finished and popped off the stack, which will cause last activity
> on stack to call `onResume()`.

on Another hand

> If you are calling finish() on an activity and manually starting a new
> activity with `new Intent()` then on stack, new activity will be on
> top and will start its own activity [life-cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#:%7E:text=to%20App%20Architecture.-,Activity%2Dlifecycle%20concepts,activity%20enters%20a%20new%20state.).

**LaunchMode**

Launch mode are nothing but flags to show android that how the corresponding activity should start.

```
android:launchMode=["standard" | "singleTop" |"singleTask" | "singleInstance"]
```

standard: *Default. The system always creates a new instance of the activity in the target task and routes the intent to it.*

singleTop:
*If an instance of the activity already exists at the top of the target task, the system routes the intent to that instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance of the activity.*

A good read on [Task and Back Stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack) and [Activity Tag](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode)

---

Now coming back to your question, if you will add flag `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to your home screen activity tag under `AndroidManifest.xml` as follows -

```
<activity 
    ... 
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
</activity>
```

then activity will not be recreated and you will not get screen loading again. There are more efficient way to navigation in android and clearly this is not the best way. Using fragments and navigation architecture are available to make life easier.